# Can I get the sum of the day, the week and the month in 1 MS SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

When I have a table with the columns

- user
- points
- createdAt

Can I get all points for each user of the day, the week and the month in 1 MS SQL query?
So that the result looks something like this:

```
|user |pointsDay|pointsWeek|pointsMonth|
|user1|   12    |    50    |   200     |
|user2|   10    |    60    |   222     |
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This help you,

```
    SELECT [USER],
        SUM(POINTS) POINTSMONTH,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CREATEDATE>DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) THEN POINTS ELSE 0 END) POINTSWEEK,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CREATEDATE>DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) THEN POINTS ELSE 0 END) POINTSDAY
    FROM USERS
    WHERE CREATEDATE> DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY [USER]
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `SUM(Points)` summarizes whole range, even those older than year.

Comment: I agree, i have provided the generic query.So that he can modify according his need.

Comment: Now i have updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Now it looks like mine, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('user1', 100, DATEADD(DAY,-50,GETDATE())),
    ('user1', 2, DATEADD(DAY,-15,GETDATE())),
    ('user1', 3, DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE())),
    ('user1', 7, GETDATE()),
    ('user2', 4, GETDATE())
    )T([User],Points,CreatedAt)
)  --Test data

SELECT [User],
    SUM(Points) Monthly,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedAt>DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) THEN Points ELSE 0 END) Weekly,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedAt>DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) THEN Points ELSE 0 END) Daily
FROM Src
WHERE CreatedAt > DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
GROUP BY [User]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use subqueries to get every calculation that you need.

```
select user,
       (select sum(points) from my_table as points where points.user = users.user and createdAt = getDate()) as pointsDay,
       (select sum(points) from my_table as points where points.user = users.user and datepart(week, createdAt) = datepart(week, getDate()) and datepart(year, createdAt) = datepart(year, getDate())) as pointsWeek,
       (select sum(points) from my_table as points where points.user = users.user and datepart(month, createdAt) = datepart(month, getDate()) and datepart(year, createdAt) = datepart(year, getDate())) as pointsMonth,
from my_table as users
group by user
```